# how to access nested JSON object values using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am facing issue in converting json response in a required format.
Request:

```
{
   "firstName": "ABC",
   "middleName": "V",
   "AddrCity": "CITY",
   "AddressLine2": "ADDRESS LINE 2",
   "LastName": "LASTNAME",
   "AddressLine1": "ADDR LINE1",
   "Country": "India",
   "customerId": "1234",
   "AddrPinCode": "999999"
}
```

Below is the response i am getting
Response:

```
{"return": 
 {
   "response": [{"$": 1234}],
   "responseMessage": [{"$": "Success ABC"}],
   "responseCode": [{"$": "CITY,India"}]
 }
}
```

Notice the "$" symbol, which is giving problem while fetching the response. 
Below is the expected response and also need to fetch response, responseMessage & responseCode values accordingly

```
{"return": 
 {
   "response": 1234,
   "responseMessage": "Success ABC",
   "responseCode": "CITY,India"
 }
}
```

Thanks for your quick response in advance.

Comment: Please format the code properly - this is not readable right now.

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: Can you please slowly explain the thing? It is hard to understand

Comment: When i getting the response, json object contains "$", with which i am not able to fetch the values using obj.result.response as "1234".

Comment: The response format is not perfect, but it's valid, and you can access the properties like this: `response.return[keyName][0]['$']` being `response` the parsed object and `keyName` the property you want to access.

Comment: when tested in w3c schools https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_object_bracket, it is working but giving exception when testing in Oracle BPEL with TypeError: Cannot read property "$" from undefined (JScript#95)

Comment: This worked for me ; thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value inside the JSON using `bracket notation`.

```js
var str = '{"return": {"response": [{"$": 1234}],"responseMessage": [{"$": "Success ABC"}],"responseCode": [{"$": "CITY,India"}]}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj.return.response[0]['$']);
console.log(obj.return.responseMessage[0]['$']);
console.log(obj.return.responseCode[0]['$']);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can use `array#foreach` and `Object.key()` to get the desired object.

```js
var str = '{"return": {"response": [{"$": 1234}],"responseMessage": [{"$": "Success ABC"}],"responseCode": [{"$": "CITY,India"}]}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(str);

Object.keys(obj.return).forEach((key) => {
  obj.return[key] = obj.return[key][0]['$'];
});

console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj={"return": 
 {
   "response": [{"$": 1234}],
   "responseMessage": [{"$": "Success ABC"}],
   "responseCode": [{"$": "CITY,India"}]
 }
};

obj.return.response[0].['$'];
obj.return.responseMessage[0].['$'];
obj.return.responseCode[0].['$'];
```

Try out this solution:

Comment: tried this too, its failing with same error <pre><exception 
 class="org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError">
TypeError: Cannot read property "$" from undefined (JScript#102)
<f>com.collaxa.cube.engine.rhino.JSContextFactory.doTopCall#109</f>
<f>org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall#3091</f>
<f>com.collaxa.cube.engine.rhino.JS.exec#279</f>
</exception>
</pre>

Comment: I have some slightly change, now you can try.

Comment: this gives a compile time error - "missing name after . operator" - syntax error

Comment: Thanks All for the support, i did certain other changes to the code and the above suggested code snippet worked. <br>obj.return["response"][0]["$"]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this two ways

**Way 1:(preferred)**

```js
        let str = `{"return":
                     {
                       "response": [{"$": 1234}],
                       "responseMessage": [{"$": "Success ABC"}],
                       "responseCode": [{"$": "CITY,India"}]
                     }
                    }`;
    
    
        let js_object = JSON.parse(str); // parse json string to javascript object
        let js_object_return = js_object.return;
        let formated_obj = {};
        let desired_obj = {};
        Object.keys(js_object_return).forEach(function(key) {
            formated_obj[key] = js_object_return[key][0]["$"];
        });
        desired_obj['return']=formated_obj;
        console.log(desired_obj.return.response);
```

**Way 2:**

```js
let regex = /\[{"\$": ("?([a-z0-9A-Z\s,]+"?))}\]/gm;
        let str = `{"return":
                     {
                       "response": [{"\$": 1234}],
                       "responseMessage": [{"\$": "Success ABC"}],
                       "responseCode": [{"\$": "CITY,India"}]
                     }
                    }`;
        let  subst = `$1`;
    
        // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
        let result = str.replace(regex, subst);
        let desired_object = JSON.parse(result); // parse json string to javascript object
        
        console.log(desired_object.return.response);
```